# Select all Data from XML

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a XML like  the sample given bellow.I want to select the information from Apply and Value irrespective  of NameValue Id .Any idea how to achieve this ?

```
<NameValueList>
        <NameValue Id="LegacyB2BRCOMM">
        <DSAttributeList /> 
        <Apply>false</Apply> 
       <Value>False</Value> 
      </NameValue>

      <NameValue Id="Persist">
      <DSAttributeList /> 
      <Apply>false</Apply> 
      <Value>False</Value> 
      </NameValue>
       ....
      </NameValueList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends in which language you are doint this, but you should use an xpath expression like this

```
//NameValue
```

and then iterate through all returned elements and access the apply and value elements.
In XQuery it would be:

```
for $nv in //NameValue
let $apply := $nv/Apply
let $value := $nv/Value
...
return <apply>{$apply}</apply><value>{$value}</value>
```

**EDIT:**

As you have changed your question to C# I would also suggest another option than the one  below.

You can use the Linq-to-XML construct of XElement in C#, to query XML

An C# version of the XQuery above would be:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString); //xmlString is where your xml string goes
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = from nv in xml.Descendants("NameValue")
                                 select new {Apply = nv.Element("Apply").Value, Value = nv.Element("Value").Value};
//Then you can iterate through
foreach(element in elements)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(myXml);

XmlNode xn = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("NameValueList/NameValue[@Id='LegacyB2BRCOMM']");
string apply = xn.SelectSingleNode("Apply").InnerText;
string value = xn.SelectSingleNode("Value").InnerText;
```

Or to iterate thru all:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(myXml);

XmlNodeList xnl = xdoc.SelectNodes("NameValueList/NameValue");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnl)
{
    string id = xn.Attributes["Id"].Value;
    string apply = xn.SelectSingleNode("Apply").InnerText;
    string value = xn.SelectSingleNode("Value").InnerText;
}
```